# about "please be advised"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> Please be advised you have until Friday of this week to be finished.

I understood what this sentence means. But can you separate the sentence into phrases or clauses?

If I separate it, one is "please be advised you", another is "until Friday of this week", the other one is "to be finished". Where can I put the "have"?

I mean I need an explanation about that sentence grammatically.

Comment: "Please be advised you" doesn't make sense in English.

Comment: @RegDwighт: [Please be advised you](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Please+be+advised+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)'re on shaky ground there. I might advise ***that*** you shouldn't delete the word "that" in my first sentence - but that's a stylistic choice which imho is less defensible in this second sentence anyway! The most unnatural aspect of OP's sentence is that native speakers would normally end it with *"...to finish"*, not *"...to be finished"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was not talking about "please be advised you *verb*". That's precisely what the OP *fails* to parse the sentence as. He is talking about "please be advised you", period. And then proceeds to wonder what a verb is doing there at all. That makes no sense with or without a *that*.

Comment: Well, *Please be advised* is an almost irrelevant introductory clause, and *of this week* is also a largely redundant qualifier. Grammatically, all we've really got here is *"**You have** [an obligation]"*. That fact that you can (optionally) include the word "that" in some rephrasings doesn't seem particularly relevant to the question, nor does it seem essential for reasons of either clarity or grammar. But having been forced to think about it a bit more, I now think the question is effectively General Reference (apart from the *to finish/be finished* difference not even asked about! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you insert *that* between *advised* and *you*, I think you will see that the sentence is made up of one main clause and one subordinate clause.

Answer (score 1):

Please be advised

(that) you have until Friday

of this week

to be finished.